# Mean centered covariate in lm and summary printing showing actual mean value

Tags: r, printing, lm, summary, r-exams

I am writing some exercises using r-exams and I went in to this problem: I am making some simple linear model fitting using a mean centered covariate, here is the code:

```r
## DATA GENERATION
set.seed(123)
n<-rpois(1,120)
age<-runif(n,0,25)
m_age<-round(mean(age),4)
wght<-100+.8*age+rnorm(n,0,4)

z0_aw<-data.frame(age,weight=wght)

m0<-lm(weight~I(age-m_age),data=z0_aw)
summary(m0)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - m_age), data = z0_aw)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -9.2226 -2.4603 -0.2445  2.3565 13.0428 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)    110.02678    0.36571  300.86   <2e-16 ***
#> I(age - m_age)   0.78432    0.05069   15.47   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.888 on 111 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.6832, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6804 
#> F-statistic: 239.4 on 1 and 111 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

m1<-lm(weight~I(age-12.679),data=z0_aw)
summary(m1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - 12.679), data = z0_aw)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -9.2226 -2.4603 -0.2445  2.3565 13.0428 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)     110.02678    0.36571  300.86   <2e-16 ***
#> I(age - 12.679)   0.78432    0.05069   15.47   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.888 on 111 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.6832, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6804 
#> F-statistic: 239.4 on 1 and 111 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, output of call in summary of model `m0` is
`lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - m_age), data = z0_aw)`

I want to obtain the same output as in model `m1`, that is
`lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - 12.679), data = z0_aw)`

However, the usage of object m_age is absolutely needed since the exercise is generated at random to avoid fraud in exams. I just tried something like `lm(weight~I(age-eval(m_age)),data=z0_aw)` but the output in call of the summary is `lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - eval(m_age)), data = z0_aw)`

For me is very important to achieve the output `lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - 12.679), data = z0_aw)`, since it will be used in some questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just `eval(m_age)` I would build up the call for the entire `lm()` and then only substitute `m_age` with its value. You can do so by:

```
cl <- call("lm", formula = weight ~ I(age - m_age), data = as.name("z0_aw"))
cl$formula[[3]][[2]][[3]] <- m_age
cl
## lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - 12.679), data = z0_aw)
```

As a brief explanation:

- The `call()` to the function named `"lm"` is constructed with two arguments `formula =` and `data =`. The formula is symbolic anyway and hence can be evaluated and the data name `"z0_aw"` is coerced to a "symbol" or "name" rather than being evaluated to a `data.frame`.
- In `cl$formula` we then replace the symbol/name `m_age` with the numeric value `12.679`. This is in the right-hand side of the formula (3rd element), in the argument of `I()` (2nd element), in the right-hand side of the difference (3rd element).

Finally, evaluating that call yields the desired `lm` object:

```
m <- eval(cl)
summary(m)
## Call:
## lm(formula = weight ~ I(age - 12.679), data = z0_aw)
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -9.2226 -2.4603 -0.2445  2.3565 13.0428 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)     110.02678    0.36571  300.86   <2e-16 ***
## I(age - 12.679)   0.78432    0.05069   15.47   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 3.888 on 111 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.6832, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6804 
## F-statistic: 239.4 on 1 and 111 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```